# cTurtle user input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am learning how to use cTurtle and one of the requirements is to ask user for input. Does it matter where you put the user input statement? Should the all the perimeters already be established first? I am not clear on this, this is my first time using cTurtle. I know that the end result should have a hexagon with a color fill.

```
import cTurtle
turtle=cTurtle.Turtle()
turtle.pensize(5)
turtle.pencolor(0.1,0.5,1.0)
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.goto(0,0)
turtle.down()
#turtle.down()
turtle.right(45)
turtle.goto(25,0)
turtle.left(45)
turtle.goto(12.5,25)
turtle.left(45)
turtle.goto(0,0)
turtle.end_fill()
```

This is all I have, it produces a  blue triangle with no fill. I just want to see what it would look like to have this ask for a user input. I am using python 3.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the input() function to get user input: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input

You don't say what the user input is for, but say it's for the color of the fill and/or the number of sides in the polygon drawn, you can do this at the beginning of your program:

```
color = input('Enter color of fill:')
num_sides = input('Enter number of polygon sides:')
num_sides = int(num_sides) # convert string to integer
```

and then use the input to set the pencolor used, or to compute the angles/lines needed to draw an N-sided polygon.

Beware no error checking is done on the user input in the code above, but you'd probably want to make sure color is an appropriate value before using it in cTurtle functions and to catch the exception when the user doesn't enter a numeric value for number of sides.